# How can I pass 'yes' response when npm installing on Dockerfile

Tags: bash, docker, npm, dockerfile, npm-install

I have a Dockerfile like below :

```
FROM node:latest

RUN npm install something && \
    npm install something && \
    npm install something
```

I want to pass 'yes' response for all required 'yes/no' param when npm installing.
Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Did you try `npm install --yes something`?

Comment: @naveenchandru phantomjs

Answer (score 25):

I used the following to install Angular without usage statistics sharing.

```
RUN echo n | npm install -g --silent @angular/cli
```

I think `echo y` should work for you

Comment: The flag --silent seems to be enough

Comment: it wasn't enough for me.

Comment: I think you may want this [here](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/init)

Answer (score 17):

There's the `yes` command specifically for this in linux:

```
RUN yes | npm install something && \
    npm install something && \
    yes yes | npm install something
```

The first line outputs a list of "y" to the first npm install command. The `yes` command also takes an option of what you want it to output. So if you need to output "yes" instead of a single "y" character per line, then you can run `yes yes` as seen in the third example.

Comment: Brilliant! That's exactly what I needed